# parse the contents of JSON data flutter

Tags: flutter

I need some help in parse the contents of JSON data flutter,

the is the response from API

```
[
    {
        "kid_id": 21,
        "par_id": 2,
        "kid_name": "omar",
        "kid_image": "The URL",
        "driver": {
            "driver_id": 13,
            "name": "Ahmad Ahmad"
        }
    }
]
```

I made the model from the https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

but I can't know how to prase the contents of JSON data, I try using the below code, but I receive data but it does not show in list builder, can anyone help me ??

this is my all code:

https://github.com/mohmmed750/Jsonfile/blob/master/parseJson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of _myString. You can directly call method over there.

```
future: _getUsers(),
```

You are getting list of kids, so you have to use iteration and convert all into MyKids object.

Change Following line

```
users.add(MyKids.fromJson(jsonData));
```

To:

```
jsonData.forEach((element) {
  users.add(MyKids.fromJson(element));
});
```

Also remove

```
setState(() {
  loading = true;
});
```

And you can access user's following

```
itemCount: asyncSnapshot.data.length,
```

Moreover, you can now make your List Method variable.

Comment: thank you, that's work very good

Answer (score 1):

The Models will be:

```
    class ClassName {
        int kidId;
        int parId;
        String kidName;
        String kidImage;
        Driver driver;

        ClassName({
            this.kidId,
            this.parId,
            this.kidName,
            this.kidImage,
            this.driver,
        });

        factory ClassName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ClassName(
            kidId: json["kid_id"],
            parId: json["par_id"],
            kidName: json["kid_name"],
            kidImage: json["kid_image"],
            driver: Driver.fromJson(json["driver"]),
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "kid_id": kidId,
            "par_id": parId,
            "kid_name": kidName,
            "kid_image": kidImage,
            "driver": driver.toJson(),
        };
    }

    class Driver {
        int driverId;
        String name;

        Driver({
            this.driverId,
            this.name,
        });

        factory Driver.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Driver(
            driverId: json["driver_id"],
            name: json["name"],
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "driver_id": driverId,
            "name": name,
        };
    }
```

And to parse,

```
    List<ClassName> classNameFromJson(String str) => 
    List<ClassName>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => ClassName.fromJson(x)));
```

Declare your vairable like:

```
    List<ClassName> myClass;
    myClass = classNameFromJson(response.body);
```